# Ajax.BeginForm() not working asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to learn ASP.Net MVC and i'm having trouble getting Ajax.BeginForm to update a partial view asynchronously.
This is the code in the view for the action:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "get",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "restaurantList"
            }))

{
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name." />
}

@Html.Partial("_Restaurants", Model)
```

The check for an ajax request in the action always returns false and the entire screen is updated rather then just the partial view. It looks like this:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_Restaurants", model);
            }

            return View(model);
```

I'm including a bunch of jquery script files in the BundleConfig.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/otf").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-{version}.js",));
```

I'm calling the render function right before the end of the body section in a shared layout view that is used by all views in my project

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/otf")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

I've been trying to solve this for 2 days but i'm getting nowhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Disable bundling with BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false and check in your browser debug windows if all require scripts were actually loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script is present in your `Scripts` folder and fetched in a `<script>` tag.

If it isn't make sure you have installed the [`Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/3.2.3) NuGet in your project which will add this script to the `Scripts` folder of you application.

I have noticed that with Visual Studio 2015 when creating a new ASP.NET MVC application this script isn't present out of the box and I had to install this NuGet in order to have it available. I don't know the reason of this script being removed in the latest MVC version - maybe it's deprecated and now there's an alternative way to achieve that but it's been a long time since I've been doing some MVC development and I am not quite sure what is the recommended way now.

Comment: I've tried this as well but it didn't work. In the element tab in the developer tools in Chrome this line is present: <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script> this means the script was loaded, right?

Comment: Yes, if you can see this script present then it should be loaded. You might also check the `Network` tab to ensure that a request is made to it and the server actually returns its contents: 200 status code. Also make sure that the jquery script is also included before it. By the way I have just created a new MVC application in VS 2015, installed the NuGet referred in my answer and was able to have the async AJAX form.

Comment: I do get the 200 status code and jquery-1.10.2 is the first script to be loaded.  I'm using VS 2015 as well and have installed Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax.3.2.3. Still won't work.

Comment: Wait it actually works now! Not sure what i changed but thank you for the help!